# High Availability in Open Source Puppet Version 4.10

Tags: open-source, puppet, devops, high-availability

I want to setup a **High Availability** environment using **Open Source Puppet** **version 4.10**.

- I did some research and found that master less architecture can be a
  solution with it trades offs (No pinpoint to failed process)
- High Availability in Puppet Enterprise is available is there a way to mimic that in open source and using foreman for GUI?

Comment: These are good questions, but quite off topic for SO.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I know this is quit off topic for SO, I have posted this query on google puppet group as well as on puppetlabs but did not get any clear answers so tried posting it here

Comment: Ok here are quick answers for you: 1. Are you doing cloud, immutable infrastructure, or container orchestration? If yes, then masterless works well. If not, then probably not. 2. HA in PE is not available out of the box until a later version than you specified, so the same solutions apply to both for enabling HA. Foreman would be irrelevant here.